# Widget text exibe apenas 1 caracter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou iniciando no flutter agora, e no meu primeiro App (que deve exibir frases aleatorias conforme aperta um botão) ele esta dando um problema, ao inves de exibir as frases, ele exibe apenas um unico caracter. Creio que eu deva estar deixando passar algo, alguem consegue me dar uma luz?
Segue o codigo:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lightGreen,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Frases do dia'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _numeroRandom = 0;
  List _fraseDoDia = [
    'A persistência é o caminho do êxito.',
    'O sucesso nasce do querer, da determinação e persistência em se chegar a um objetivo. Mesmo não atingindo o alvo, quem busca e vence obstáculos, no mínimo fará coisas admiráveis.',
    'Só existe um êxito: a capacidade de levar a vida que se quer.',
    'A coragem não é ausência do medo; é a persistência apesar do medo.',
    'Só se pode alcançar um grande êxito quando nos mantemos fiéis a nós mesmos',
    'O homem não teria alcançado o possível se, repetidas vezes, não tivesse tentado o impossível'
  ];

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {

      _numeroRandom = new Random().nextInt(5);

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Pressione o botão para gerar uma frase:',
            ),
            Text(
              _fraseDoDia[_numeroRandom],
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add_box),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Fiz alguns testes com o exemplo que passou e exibiu corretamente, tente tirar o `style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1` para ver se resolve.

Comment: Acabei de testar em um dispositivo real aqui, e funcionou normalmente. Aparentemente o problema era do Virtual Device, que estava com algum bug que provocava isto. Valeu!